# How to make cell text colored if cell contains a formula?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to create a conditional formatting where cells are colored whenever they contain a formula. Is this possible with Google Spreadsheets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Conditional Formatting Custom Formula. Right click on cell A1. From the dropdown list click Conditional Formatting. From the Conditionl Format Rules popup panel, set up Conditional Formula as follows:

Apply to Range:

A1:Z1000

From the Format cells if.. option, click the down arrow. Select Custom Formula is (note you may need to scroll down. It is the last option).

Custom Formula is:

```
=isformula(A1)
```

Formatting Style:

Pick you option.

Any cell in the Apply to Range that has a formula will get your selected formatting style.